# how to get the save card details on another activity of the user from razorpay android

Tags: android, credit-card, razorpay

I have saved the card details in checkoutActivity but after transaction i want to fetch saved cards on another activity, how to achieve this ?

```
        JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
        options.put("name", "Razorpay Corp");
        options.put("description", "Purchase");
        options.put("currency", "INR");
        options.put("save", "1");
        String payment = editTextPayment.getText().toString();
        double total = Double.parseDouble(payment);
        total = total * 100;
        options.put("amount", total);

        JSONObject preFill = new JSONObject();
        preFill.put("email", "test@gmail.com");
        preFill.put("contact", sharedPref.getString("Mobile", ""));
        options.put("prefill", preFill);
```

Comment: initialize static callback or store in static fields or use local storage and display values

Comment: but how can i fetch that to store it in local storage? it is razorpay api that inilializes so that how can i fetch saved cards of a particlular user?

Comment: hello @AshwinJawale have you got any solution?

Comment: @ChiragPatel didnt got any