# How to get saved card details razorpay android

Tags: android, payment, credit-card, razorpay

I am trying to retrieve saved card details in android I implemented [Razorpay](https://razorpay.com/) payment gateway my requirement is to show user saved card details to the user how do I implement this.

this is what i done so far

```
val options = JSONObject()
options.put("name","Razorpay Corp")
options.put("description","Demoing Charges")
//You can omit the image option to fetch the image from dashboard
options.put("image","https://s3.amazonaws.com/rzp-mobile/images/rzp.png")
options.put("theme.color", "#3399cc");
options.put("currency","INR");
options.put("amount","50000")//pass amount in currency subunits

val retryObj = JSONObject()
retryObj.put("enabled", true)
retryObj.put("max_count", 4)
options.put("retry", retryObj)

val preFill = JSONObject()

preFill.put("email", "mitesh@yo.com")

preFill.put("contact", "9011111111")

options.put("prefill",preFill)
co.open(activity,options)
```

I find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082044/how-to-get-the-save-card-details-on-another-activity-of-the-user-from-razorpay-a) but a solution is not available that's why I am asking again

I don't know is it possible or not

Please help me any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i asked this [question](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-android-sample-app/issues/225) to the razorpay team and they provide me the solution

you have to add customer id and save in your object so it will save your card detail

```
options.put("customer_id", "cust_4lsdkfldlteskf");
options.put("save", "1");
```

you can create customer using razorpay [add customer](https://razorpay.com/docs/customers/#api-actions) api

below is the curl of add customer

```
curl -u <YOUR_KEY_ID>:<YOUR_KEY_SECRET> \
-X POST https://api.razorpay.com/v1/customers \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "name":"Gaurav Kumar",
  "contact":"9123456780",
  "email":"gaurav.kumar@example.com",
  "fail_existing":"0",
  "gstin":"29XAbbA4369J1PA",
  "notes":{
    "notes_key_1":"Tea, Earl Grey, Hot",
    "notes_key_2":"Tea, Earl Grey… decaf."
  }
}'
```

to retrieve card details you have to call [fetch all tokens of customer](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/custom/features/saved-cards/#step-4-fetch-all-tokens-of-customer) api below is curl

```
curl -u <YOUR_KEY_ID>:<YOUR_KEY_SECRET> \-X GET https://api.razorpay.com/v1/customers/:customer_id/tokens
```

**<YOUR_KEY_ID> is your key which start from rzp_*****

**<YOUR_KEY_SECRET> you have to generate from razorpay from website Setting>api keys**

[image: from website]

Hope this will solve your issue